# How should hard hitting music like EDM be mastered?

Tags: mastering, electronic-music

I'm in the process of mixing and finishing a hard EDM track. It has a lot of bass and highs and it's transients are really hard and tight. I've come across [this article](https://www.masteringthemix.com/blogs/learn/mixing-and-mastering-using-lufs) which talks about LUFS and how tracks these days should be more dynamic. I've never heard of LUFS before except the fact that for most streaming platforms I know -16 of -12 is now the standard.

My LUFS readout for the entire track now are:

[image]

I also found this [mastering tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U25Dwe-JQdg&t=186s) here which does a decent job of mastering the track in my opinion but it's peaking way higher than my track at this point is doing.

The track has to be played on streaming services like Youtube and Soundcloud but it also has to preform well in a club without it sounding weak and quieter than other tracks.

I would like to know if this is a problem and would I be wrong following this tutorial? Are there any good tutorials on this topic that are accurate? Should I master the track differently for club use than for streaming services?

Comment: If you want your track to play nicely in a club , you'll have to mix to a bigger cone diameter to emulate club speakers ,and also a sub (and maybe a bigger room). Most of the tracks mixed nowadays just play well in a room , cause this is the place where they are mixed. Keep in mind that Mastering is the final stage of the song production chain , little can be done to steer the final result to a direction. Big decisions must be taken while mixing. Mastering is not a magic wand, it can only somewhat magnify the mixing decisions made and generally apply soft touches to the initial material.

Comment: The track is sent to me almost compleatly mixed. I only had to do some minor tweaks like high passing rumbling sounds and stuff like that. I just need to master it as my enviorment is better treated for that stuff

Comment: You can't learn to master well from a tutorial. It's not a step by step process that is well documented. It's an artistic process that takes years to learn and practice. Imagine asking, "How do I play this Beethoven symphony on the violin? I watched a video on violin playing but my playing doesn't sound like the professionals sound." We can't tell you how to master on a Q&A site like this. It's too complicated and subtle.

Comment: you could at least give general directions on maybe articles of video's that explain the concept of LUFS...

Comment: That's kind of a separate question, and should be asked on it's own.  Todd is totally right, you can't just give a step by step guide for this stuff. Also, if you're looking for articles, Google is a better choice than this stack..